# Can I export appliance with all the snapshots in VirtualBox (Version 5.1.28)?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, backup, snapshot

I use Oracle VM VirtualBox *Version 5.1.28 r117968 (Qt5.6.2)* . I have two virtual machines (Windows 7 64bit and Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) with 8 snapshots in Windows and 6 snapshots in Ubuntu. I want to have a backup of the two virtual machines **with all the snapshots**. I know there is a **clone** option. But is there any other options? If yes, what are those and how to do those?

[Oracle VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nadva.png)

[P:S: I want to move the backups to my external hard drive.]

> UPDATES:---------------------------------------------------

I took screenshots of inside of `VirtualBox VMs` folder and inside `Snapshots` folder. Please look at them. It seems that the snapshots are copied as well if I copy the Whole `VirtualBox VMs` folder. So, can I restore the snapshots by just copying and pasting in future?

[image: Inside <code>VirtualBox VMs</code> folder] 
[image: Inside <code>Snapshots</code> folder]

Comment: You may try to copy all the VirtualBox XML files from VM folder and also all the VM snapshots without changing file name and file path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to backup all VMs just copy **Virtualbox VMs** folder. This will backup all VMs info including **snapshots**.  To restore the backup just copy all folder to the same path or edit VM xml file with ussually with **.vbox** extension

Comment: How can I be sure that this method will also backup the snapshots?

Comment: @jabi It won’t not unless you clone the virtual drive with the vbox utility tool or whatever it’s called check the Virtual Box manual for more information

Comment: What about Export Appliance feature? Will this feature backup all the snapshots as well?

Comment: `user809676` is saying that copying the Virtualbox VMs folder will include the snapshots as well. But you (`Ramhound`)are saying it won't. I am confused. :(

Comment: Usually snapshots are stored in a subfolder placed at VM´s main folder unless you specify a different path.

Comment: I updated my question with screenshots. Please check

Answer (score 1):

The best solution IMO is to clone the VM, and the create an archive and then move it.

If you copy the folder into a new drive, then try to bring up the VM in the backup and the VM itself, one of them wont work. This is because, when you copy the VM, it preserves the UUIDs for the machine, the HDD and the image.

However, when you clone the VM, it creates new UUIDs for the Machine, HDD, and the image. So you can then bring both the VM and the backup of the VM up at the same time. You can also copy the cloned image to another computer etc etc.. and it will work everywhere.

The advantage of `Exporting an Appliance` is that it will create a single package, and it can then be moved between `VirtualBox` and say `VMware`. However, the disadvantage of this is that it wont contain any stapshots you may have in your VM. If you are ok with sacrificing the snapshots, this may be the best and most portable solution.

If you want to keep the snapshots, then you can create the clone, zip it up and create a backup. Then if you need to transfer the VM to another VM software (`VMware), just fire up the backup, and export the VM as a`.ova` file and transfer it to the new VM software.